# Can I set a form_state redirect with a destination parameter in form submission?

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I've built a "Quick Links" drop-down select box for my Drupal-based web app. The select box is implemented as a standard Drupal form, which appears on all pages in the site. When the user selects an option and submits the form, I want to redirect the user to the appropriate page, but have them return to the original page when they have finished.

e.g. user is on node/5, and selects a quick link which takes them to another form. When they have completed this form, I want them to be returned to node/5.

I have achieved this in other parts of the system using drupal_get_destination to append the ?destination=node/5 querystring parameter to the destination form, and this works nicely. However, in my quicklinks form submit handler, I'm setting form_state['redirect'] to set the target page, and if I add the ?destination= parameter it gets URL-encoded, and so isn't picked up when my target form is submitted.

```
function dh_seo_quick_links_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = $form['#link_targets'][$link].'?'.drupal_get_destination();
}
```

Have I gone about this completely the wrong way? Is this redirection even possible? Could I do something clever with the $_REQUEST variables directly?

Comment: May be neater to have the page load in an overlay. So  you won't have to worry about the rerturn variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - I've worked it out. It seems that if you set a relative URL in the $form_state['redirect'] it gets URL-encoded, but an absolute URL will not:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'myform?'.drupal_get_destination();
```

redirects to myform%3Fdestination%3Dnode%252F5

```
global $base_url;
$form_state['redirect'] = $base_url.'/myform?'.drupal_get_destination();
```

redirects to myform?destination=node/5, which is what I wanted.

Comment: the proper way of doing this is the one stated by Ben Smiley.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a nice solution for Drupal 7 which allows you to use relative paths:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/[node number]',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'variable_name' => 'value',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'hash_fragment'
  ),    
);
```

This code creates the following url:

```
..?node/[node number]&variable_name=value#hash_fragment
```

This allows you a lot of flexibility while taking advantage of the Drupal framework.

Comment: Much cleaner and complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can supply an array for `$form_state['redirect']` and put the destination query as second parameter. For example:

```php
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
 'myform', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're answer worked for me Mark. Thanks!

You can do it this way also:

```
global $base_url;
$form['#redirect'] = $base_url .'/'. $form['#redirect'] .'?test=hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this solution:

```
global $base_url;
$form_state['redirect'] = $base_url . '/myform?' . drupal_get_destination();
```

Comment: global? probably not the best way.